# Can I recharge an SRAM's internal battery with only power pins?

Tags: memory, charging

I was wondering if it was possible to recharge PCMCIA SRAM Card (with an internal rechargeable battery) using just the Vcc and Ground pins.

A little background info: A piece of medical equipment from the early 90's uses an SRAM card, with some data files / executables on it. We tried replacing the replaceable battery, no luck. We figured we needed to copy the backup SRAM files from the backup floppy disk back onto the SRAM Card. Long story short, I found an old XP laptop, the laptop recognized the card, did a lazy job of reformatting it (through XP gui to FAT) and just copied the files over. The manual for the medical device said to use the command Format F:/U/S (Assuming F is the Drive letter assigned to the disk) but the XP command prompt's commands don't match the required MS-DOS so the command didn't work (and I couldn't figure out equivalents). I thought it might work my way. Of course it didn't. The card was in the machine about 10 minutes. After we realized it wasn't going to work we took it out and tried to put it back in the laptop, but it wouldn't get recognized by the laptop anymore.

Edit: I'm going to be using Windows 98 to do the formatting command, upon further reading it looks like the /U (unconditional formatting) switch was removed in MS-DOS 7.x, now all formatting is unconditional by default) so now my command would be F:/S. (Assuming F is the Drive letter assigned.)

I'm afraid maybe reformatting it and putting it in the machine may have corrupted the card somehow.

Under the assumption that the replaceable battery is dependent on the internal battery having a charge in order for the card to be operational, my hope is that the card's internal battery had enough charge so that I was able to do those operations but then died completely when in the machine. Maybe the internal battery wasn't getting charged when it was in the laptop or in the machine. I've read that power management must be disabled in the bios and windows in order for the card to receive a charge and will be testing this.

I will be checking pins 63 & 64 (Battery detect) to see if the internal battery is ok, but didn't even realize that was a possibility until posting this question.

TLDR:

Without hooking up any other pins besides ground, if I were to put a 5v ~15mA current to pin 17 (Vcc) do you think this will recharge the internal battery?

Link to SRAM card.

http://vikant.com/PCMCIA-SRAM-Card.pdf

Link to the medical device (SRAM section).

http://www.spectrumxray.com/sites/default/files/pdfs/GE-OEC-C-Arms.pdf#page=183

Comment: So, just to be clear, you re-formatted the SRAM card that had the files on it that you wanted? Then say goodbye to the files.

Comment: No I had the files on the backup floppy disk. I formatted the SRAM so that XP was able to access the card and copy the files to it.

Comment: Yes. You might try charghing the battery in this way.

Comment: As Dorian says - it seems that recharge MAY work applying Vcc and ground. Read the BVD1 & BVD2 nites re monitoring the battery status.

Comment: I'm not sure if you intended to delete most of the question, as you have done. Without eg the text you provided it is not possible to understand the question and without the links it is not possible to check what you are asking (as I and Dorian did).

Comment: Sorry Russell, I will restore it, I was just trying to make the question more on-topic to take the question off hold. But I can't think of how to rephrase my question to be more about the "Design" of electronics vs the "Use".